# Can't shutdown Ubuntu 16.04 after a long session

Tags: 16.04, grub2, shutdown

I have Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit version installed on my laptop and I have a strange problem. After working for a long time with Ubuntu (for example 2 hours), when I shutdown or reboot the system, it hangs on purple screen and doesn't do anything and it stays on (even longer than half an hour) until I force shutdown it by pressing the power button. But after a short session (less than an hour) it turns off and everything works fine.

I tried these options:

1. Editing line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` in `/etc/default/grub` file to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=force"` for watching the shutdown process.
2. Decreasing default timeout to 5 seconds in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` file like this:

   ```
   DefaultTimeoutStartSec=5s
   DefaultTimeoutStopSec=5s
   ```

After applying these solutions, when I shut down after a long session, I see a black screen with no log at all (I see only an underscore character) and the problem still exists.

My laptop model is Acer E1-572PG and I use Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu and everything works fine in Windows.

**EDIT:**

setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to `acpi=off` didn't work for me and I have the same issue.

Comment: Does `sudo poweroff` work? Does this particular system have ANY other power-related or hardware-related issues?

Comment: No it doesn't work.

Comment: Then use the `ubuntu-bug` application to file a bug report against the `linux` package. Developers can fix only the problems they are aware of.