# Update drivers for fixing shutdown issue

Tags: 16.04, drivers

I have Ubuntu 16.04 i386 installed on my laptop and I haven't updated any driver since Ubuntu installation. Now my system has a shutdown issue that very annoying to me. After working for a long time I can't shut down, restart, or suspend the system (see this page: [Can't shutdown Ubuntu 16.04 after a long session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999643/cant-shutdown-ubuntu-16-04-after-a-long-session)). other fixes like editing the grub file didn't work for me and now I want to update all drivers to see if that will fix the issue.

Please tell me how can I update all drivers.

Comment: What makes you think "drivers" are the problem?

Comment: I have both windows 10 and ubuntu installed and I had the same issue in windows until I updated the drivers and that fixed the issue. So I think maybe that works on ubuntu too.

Comment: Drivers simply connect Windows with hardware. Exactly which hardware needed the updated driver? The driver analogy may be inappropriate -  Linux is not like Windows, and hardware compatibility works rather differently